Django formset duplication
I have used inline formsets to create a form but for some reason the fields are duplicating and I can't figure out where I have made a mistake-

Ignore the bad styling!
Edit- found where the issue is happening but still don't understand why:
{% block content %}
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="container mx-auto sm:px-4" method="post" id="recipe_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <!-- main form start --- in our case recipe form -->
    <div class="max-w-sm w-full lg:max-w-full lg:flex">
        <div class="mb-8">
            <h4 class="text-gray-900 font-bold text-xl mb-2">Add Recipe!</h4>
        </div>
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="mb-4 flex-auto p-6">
                <label>{{field.label}}</label>
                {% if field.field.required %}
                    <span style="color: red;" class="required">*</span>
                {% endif %}

                {{field}}
                {% if field.help_text %}
                    <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
                {% endif %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

It is my first attempt at using inline formsets so a bit lost to what is causing my duplication issue-
Many Thanks for the help!

There's a lot of code here...please read [mre], then [edit] your post to reduce your snippet the minimum that still replicates your problem.

@AndrewYim I only included so much as I don't know what specifically is causing the issue-

Well, read the article. It provides an approach for when you don't know what's causing the issue - read the "divide and conquer" section. If you don't know which sections are causing a problem, it'll be hard to answer your question anyways.

This line:
{{ form|crispy }}

is where the duplication was taking place. After adding the crispy tag to:
{% with named_formsets.images as formset %}
        {{ formset.management_form|crispy }}

the duplication error was fixed.
